# How to use struct keys in a map?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, enums

I am implementing some DB logic without using an ORM.

Can I somehow create a mapping between struct keys and db enums?

```golang
type Message struct {
    SomeKey string
    SomeOtherKey string
}

MessageToDBEnum: = map[ ? MessageKey] string {
    SomeKey: "some_key",
    SomeOtherKey: "some_other_key"
}
```

- can I later dynamically use the map key (eg when iterating throgh the map) to set/get struct values?
- also can I somehow assure that `MessageToDBEnum` is exhaustive (all public keys of Message are included)?

Comment: As far as I see the conversion could be achieved with https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure but I have no direct control of the Message (it is exposed by an other package)

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to convert a struct to map and vice versa. There are 3rd party libs to do that, e.g. [`github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure`](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure).

But we can do it ourselves too, it's not that hard. We may use reflection to do it. Without checking errors, here's the essence of the struct to map conversion:

```
func struct2Map(x interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    m := map[string]interface{}{}

    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    t := reflect.TypeOf(x)
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        m[t.Field(i).Name] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }

    return m
}
```

You may use it like this:

```
msg := Message{
    SomeKey:      "v1",
    SomeOtherKey: "v2",
}

m := struct2Map(msg)
fmt.Println(m)
```

Which outputs:

```
map[SomeKey:v1 SomeOtherKey:v2]
```

The backward conversion is even simpler, but know that for a function to modify a struct, you must pass a pointer to it. Again, without checking for possible errors, the essence of it is:

```
func map2Struct(m map[string]interface{}, d interface{}) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(d).Elem()
    for k, v := range m {
        s.FieldByName(k).Set(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
var msg2 Message
map2Struct(m, &msg2)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", msg2)
```

Which outputs:

```
{SomeKey:v1 SomeOtherKey:v2}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UxH7PhFaUQS).

You may build the validation into these conversion functions, and return an error or use default / zero values when an invalid value is found.

Comment: thank you!
I want to use struct fields eg `SomeKey` as the map key, not the whole struct

Comment: @GeriTol Using a struct field is no different than using a single `string` as the key, see the second half of the answer.

Comment: I would need `SomeKey` as the map key not `some_key`.
The mapping is needed to be able to persisit the struct to the DB and later retrieve it back.

Comment: @GeriTol I rewrote the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Will review it. Just posted some clarification regarding the same lib in the comments of the question before you have submitted your answer.

Comment: Yeah as far as I see using tags is not an option for me since the code has no controll over Message, it is imported from an other package